# I can't use flutter_swiper in stack widget i got Render Box error?

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-widget

I'm using this swiper in a stack widget which is enclosed in a Card widget

```
Swiper(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Container(
            // margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                )),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: post.mediaUrl,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: 10,
        viewportFraction: 0.8,
        scale: 0.9,
      ),
```

The Errors are as follows:

> ```
> ════════ Exception caught by scheduler library      ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>  RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#4a53c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE DETACHED
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1694
> pos 12: 'hasSize'
> ```

> The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of
> type FlexParentData to         a RenderObject, which has been set up
> to accept ParentData of incompatible type StackParentData.

> Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor
> RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly
> inside Flex widgets. The offending Expanded is currently placed inside
> a Stack widget.

> The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the
> incompatible parent data was:   RepaintBoundary ←
> NotificationListener ← GlowingOverscrollIndicator
> ← Scrollable ← NotificationListener ← PageView ←
> NotificationListener ← TransformerPageView ←
> Swiper ← Expanded ← ⋯